# Calculating the "distance" between two two-dimensional data series

Tags: matlab

I have two datasets (tracks) with points in x/y which represent GPS positions. I want to analyze the distance between both tracks. The points are not necessary in sync, but having the same frequency, as shown in this little excerpt (each track consists of 1000+ points):
[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Lno.png)

Due to being not in sync I can't just compare the two points which are closest to each other. And since the path is not exactly the same I can't sync the tracks. It might be a solution interpolating a curve for each dataset and then calculating the integral in between. Since the tracks are much longer than shown in the example I can't just use regression functions like polyfit.

How can this be done or are there other/better strategies for analyzing (mean/mean square...) the distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

am304's answer is by far the easiest, and probably the way to go.

However, I'd like to add a few other ways to do this, which are much more complicated, but could greatly enhance accuracy depending on your use case.

And if it's not for you, then it could be useful for anyone else passing by.

### Method 1

**Pros**: fast, easy

**Cons**: method is overly optimistic about the smoothness of the tracks

1. Determine the [B-spline representation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/curvefit/examples/constructing-spline-curves-in-2d-and-3d.html) for both tracks. You then have a parametric relation for both tracks:

   [image]
2. The distance between both tracks is then the [average of the function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average#Average_of_a_function)

   [image]

   for all applicable `t`, which is computed through the following integral:

   [image]

### Method 2

**Pros**: closest to the "physics" of the situation

**Cons**: hard to get right, specific to the situation and thus non-reusable

1. Use the equations of motion of whatever was following that track to derive a transition matrix for any arbitrary time step `t`. When possible, also come up with an appropriate noise model.
2. Use a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) to re-sample both tracks to some equally-spaced time vector, which is preferably different from the time vector of both track 1 and track 2.
3. Compute the distances between the `x,y` pairs thus computed, and take the average.

### Method 3

**Pros**: fast, easy

**Cons**: method is overly optimistic about the smoothness of the tracks. Both fits are biased.

1. Fit a space curve through track 1
2. [Compute the distances](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34869-distance2curve) of all points in track 2 to this space curve.
3. Repeat 1 and 2, but vice versa.
4. Take the average of all these distances.

### Method 4

**Pros**: fast, easy

**Cons**: method is overly optimistic about the smoothness of the tracks. Fit will be of lesser quality due to inherently larger noise terms.

1. Fit a space curve to the *union* of both tracks. That is, treat points from track 1 and track 2 as a single data set, through which to fit a space curve.
2. Compute the perpendicular residuals of both tracks with respect to this space curve.
3. compute the average all these distances.

### Remarks

- Note that all methods here use the flat-Earth assumption. If the tracks are truly long and cover a non-negligible portion of the Earth's surface, you'll have to compute distances via the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) rather than a mere Pythagorean root. The Kalman filter is less sensitive to this, provided your equations of motion take care of a spherical Earth.
- If you have an elevation model of the region of interest, use that. Of course depending on the area, you'd be surprised how much of a difference that makes compared to a smooth Earth.

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing following method 1 but somehow failed. It seems like the cscvn-function you linked to can only plot stuff, but not keep the parametrized tracks stored for further processing. So I downloaded a B-spline toolbox, which should be able doing that [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27047-b-spline-tools/content/bspline_tools_1_2/doc/html/BsplineDoc.html). I created splines of my datasets using Bspline and calculated the distance with "sqrt(((ux(1:2769)-rx(1:2769))).^2 + ((uy(1:2769)-ry(1:2769))).^2)" which gives the same results as without Bspline...

Comment: @user3296542: "without Bspline"; you mean by using simeple resampling, as in am304's answer?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I experienced right now, that most of my problems are due to another error source I didn't take into account right now: One of the datasets is not uniformly sampled even though it should be. Not just noise, but also very few crazy jumps (factor 100) - and maybe some undetected jitter, which isn't included in the time signal. I'll first fix that and then come back to the distance problem.

Comment: @user3296542: It is quite possible that `resample` works exactly the same way; by fitting a B-spline and then resampling according to that curve. There will nideed not be a significant difference between the continuous and discrete integrals (=sum of distances between resampled points). Out of curiosity, what do the tracks represent?

Comment: This is why a continuous integral between both B-splines should provide a better result than a discrete comparison. I resampled now with interp1, which rearranges the samples uniformly. That removes most problems. The tracks represent two GPS records of approximately the same track, one with a pretty accurate receiver and one with a crappy one which I filtered. I want to test how accurate the later one can get taking the other one as absolute accurate reference (which of course is only a very rough approximation).

Answer (score 1):

Is the x/y data logged as a function of time? If so, you can resample one or both datasets to have to same sample time vector using the [`resample`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.resample.html) function for `timeseries`. You'll have to convert your data to a `timeseries` object first, but it's worth it. Once both data sets are resampled to the same time vector, you simply subtract one from the other.

Comment: Thanks. Both are logged as a fuction of time. One having an absolute and accurate (GPS) time, the other one only a relative time since the start of this record. Both datasets are already resampled (one is downsampled to match the other frequency), roughly synced via crosscorrelation and truncated to the start/end of each other. Simply subtracting the points from each other leaves me a picture like this one here: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0zUkW.png). The maximums are roughly fitting, but most of the time the error should be below one. How can the timeseries improve that?

Comment: The errors shown in the graph might be not only due to this error. I experienced right now, that most of my problems are due to another error source I didn't take into account right now: One of the datasets is not completely uniformly sampled even though it should be. Not just noise, but also very few crazy jumps (factor 100) - and maybe some undetected jitter, which isn't included in the time signal. I'll first fix that and then come back to the distance problem.